# Transferring items from NSArray to NSSet for NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, duplicates, nsset

Two related questions:

1. When you use `[NSSet setWithArray:]`, does it remove duplicate object for you automatically?
2. How can you tell `NSSet` exactly what you want "duplicate" to mean? I.e. if you have a bunch of "College course" objects, each with a name and section number, and you wanted to transfer to an NSSet, keeping only one of each college course for a given name (for example, if you had three sections of Calculus, how would you tell it to only keep one section of calculus, even if their section numbers are different, so they're not perceived as identical by default).

Thanks! Let me know if that question was unclear at all. I was having trouble figuring out a way to word it.

Edit: This question is specific to NSManagedObjects, whose `isEqual:` method cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

   > If the same object appears more than once in array, it is added
   >   only once to the returned set.
2. Equality is determined here as throughout Cocoa with the `-isEqual:` method (and the `-hash` method). If you want two custom objects to be considered equal, you should override these appropriately, and you must override both. These are generally used so that objects that really are equivalent and generally interchangeable (but are separate objects) can be seen as such. In your example, it sounds like the college course objects really are "different" (ie, they represent different classes, even if they might share the same overall "calculus" topic), so it seems problematic to call those object instances "equal" if this is a large scale project/code base. In your case, you might consider adding the object to the set one by one and do your own comparisons as you add to make sure you get one of each "topic".

Comment: Sorry, it was a bad example, it was just what I came up with off the top of my head. I can override isEqual, and will look into the `hash` function. Haven't heard of it before. (Clearly new to iOS).

Comment: @Mason: Cool. When overriding, it's often easy to pass through the hash value of whatever internal data you're using to make the equality distinction, like the hash of the string with the course name. The hash *needs* to be the same for "equal" objects, but it doesn't have to be unique otherwise.

Comment: Uh oh, added complication. The objects i'm using are NSManagedObjects, so it's illegal to override `isEqual:`. I guess that changes the question a bit. Any tips?

Comment: @Mason: Yes, do your own uniquefication when adding to the set. :) Core Data controls the equality of managed objects, so you just can't redefine what it means to be equal. I would implement your own custom `-compareMe` method on the object, and then as you're manually looping through the array, adding objects to the set, use an inner loop to check whether anything already in the set compares the same using your new method. There may be a one-liner way to simplify those loops, but not sure.